# Google Authorship image only visible to author

Tags: seo, google-authorship

I have a website where all the links have an authorship tag added. It used to show up in the Google results properly, but for the past couple of days, it is not appearing for other users.

My photo is visible only if I search and find a URL while logged into Google. It doesn't show up for other users, it just shows my name in that case.

The tag that I am using on my website is:

```
<div id='authorShip' style='display:none'>By <a href="https://plus.google.com/110868407818568346432/" rel="author">Prashant Singh</a></div>
```

The div was kept invisible from very beginning!

What could be the possible issue?

Answer (score 3):

> The div was kept invisible from very beginning!

That's the issue - you set the style for the div as `display:none` so it's hidden.

As covered here in [Google Webmaster Tools - Author information not appearing](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1306778?hl=en), Google won't display information that can't be viewed by users:

> **Hidden markup** Make sure that your *rel="author"* link is not invisible
>   to humans using techniques like **display:none** or CSS. Broadly speaking,
>   Google won’t display any information that cannot be viewed by humans.

You should also review the other information provided there, and use the [structured data testing tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) to verify that Google can extract authorship information from your page.

Lastly, it should also be noted as covered [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1408986?expand=option2) that: `Google doesn't guarantee to show author information in Google Web Search or Google News results.`

**Update:**

There are reports in this [thread](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/webmasters/structured-data/muvbBvRuy_Y) indicating that Google has recently tightened up on displaying this, likely based on visibility and other factors covered in this [Webmaster Central Blog](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.ca/2013/08/relauthor-frequently-asked-advanced.html).

**Update 2:**

Continuing the above trend, [John Mueller](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/711/john-mueller) from Google's Webmaster Tools announced on [8/28/2014](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+JohnMueller/posts/HZf3KDP1Dm8) that Google will no longer be showing authorship results in Google Search or tracking data from content using `rel=author` markup. See [this](http://searchengineland.com/goodbye-google-authorship-201975) for more on that.